# Secuencia de Fibonacci con array Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, fibonacci

Estoy con un ejercicio de Javascript del cual me pide hacer una secuencia de Fibonacci con array iniciado en [1,1] y me pide recorrerlo hasta la posición 20, pero no encuentro el error del cual me recorre más de lo que pide.

```js
let fibonacci = [1, 1];
let numero = 0;

function mostrarSecuenciaDeFibonacci() {
    
    for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        numero = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[fibonacci.length-1];
        fibonacci.push(numero);
    }
}

mostrarSecuenciaDeFibonacci()
console.log(fibonacci)
```

Comment: El ciclo debería iniciar en 1 en vez de cero, porque en la primera iteración tratas de sumar `fibonacci[-1] + fibonacci[0]` que da error, porque no existe el elemento.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné con numero = fibonacci[i] + fibonacci[fibonacci.length-1]; y en la iteración para llegar a la posición 20 acorté el limite poniendo i=0; i<18, Gracias a todos!.

Answer (score 3):

En lugar de usar un contador, podrías simplemente mirar la longitud del array:

```js
let fibonacci = [1,1];
while (fibonacci.length < 20) {
  fibonacci.push( fibonacci[fibonacci.length -1] + fibonacci[fibonacci.length -2]);
}

console.log(fibonacci.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, la secuencia **fibonacci** debería partir de **`[0,1]`**, sino los resultados serían distintos.

Ahora el error vendría a ser aquí, de la cual te está retornando `NaN` ya que estás tratando de sumar a una posición que no existe en la iteración:

```
numero = fibonacci[i-1] + fibonacci[fibonacci.length-1];
```

Lo correcto sería de la siguiente forma:

```
numero = fibonacci.at(-1) + fibonacci.at(-2);
```

En donde **`at(-1)`** te devolverá siempre la última posición del arreglo y **`at(-2)`** la penúltima posición. Veamos:

```js
let fibonacci = [0, 1];
let numero = 0;

function mostrarSecuenciaDeFibonacci() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    numero = fibonacci.at(-1) + fibonacci.at(-2);
    fibonacci.push(numero);
  }
}

mostrarSecuenciaDeFibonacci();

console.log(fibonacci);
```

> Enlaces: **[Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at#ejemplos)**

Comment: Si usas `.at(-1)`, porque no usas también `.at(-2)` en vez de `[fibonacci.length-2]`?

Comment: Bueno el resultado sería lo mismo, ahora lo modifico, gracias.

Comment: El ejercicio está especificado para que sea de array [1,1] y no [0,1], de todos modos gracias!.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, con numero = fibonacci[i] + fibonacci[fibonacci.length-1]; y en la iteración para llegar a la posición 20 acorté el limite poniendo i=0; i<18, gracias!.

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta que te sirvió para que tu pregunta esté como respondida. También evita usar la sección de respuestas para hacer comentarios, pronto tendrás más reputación y tendrás estos privilegios, saludos.